# How to open a jQuery Mobile popup via Link without navbar highlight?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to open a popup in jQuery Mobile from within a navbar button. The problem is the little highlight (default is blue) after pressing the button. The highlight is removed after 200ms or so on a desktop browser. On a mobile device this highlight is sometimes visible after opening the popup and will not be removed when closing it. Some problem with file select on Nexus 4/10. I also added a file select: The highlight is never removed on a mobile device, on a desktop browser this is no bigger problem.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/eGFaG/1/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="ui-page">
    <div data-role="ui-header">    
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="popupTest">Popup function</a></li>
                <li><a href="#popup" data-rel="popup">Popup Link</a></li>
                <li><a id="fileUpload">File select</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <input type="file" id="fileSelect" data-role="none">
        <div id="popup" data-role="popup">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="true">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="option1" value="true">
                <label for="option1">Option #1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="option2" value="true">
                <label for="option2">Option #2</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option3" id="option3" value="true">
                <label for="option3">Option #3</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#popupTest').click(
    function(event) {
        $('#popup').popup(
            'open', {
                x: $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() / 2,
                y: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()
            }
        );

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
);

$('#fileUpload').click(
    function(event) {
        $('#fileSelect').click();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#popup fieldset {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#fileSelect {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10000px;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

I'm looking for a general way to prevent the blue highlight with offical jQuery Mobile options. Modifing the stylesheet might be an option, but the highlight is also stored internally to the control. I don't know if there are other side effects.

When opening the popup programatically there is no highlight on a desktop browser. When the navbar is used on a footer the position must be calculated in a more complex way (footer fixed?).

So is there any option that I missed? When doing something programatically when clicking a navbar button, is it correct to use event.preventDefault() and return false or is something else missing?